# Dynamically added SVG doesn't obey clipping

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm adding two SVGs, with the second having a smaller clip. However, when added with Javascript it ignores the smaller clip. Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jraynolds/pen/zyNBPv) illustrating the problem: the first is dynamically added and the second isn't. The second works, but the first doesn't.

Here's the relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#svgHolder").append(createSVG("field", fieldShape, "red", shieldPath));
    $("#svgHolder").append(createSVG("division", fessShape, "blue"));
});

var color = function(className, color, type) {
    $("." + className).css("fill", "#" + color);
}

var shieldPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
shieldPath.id = "fieldShield";
shieldPath.setAttribute("d", "m395,20c0.910,57.6 0.857,115 0,173-0.833,55.5-    3.60,98.8-28.5,133-29.9,40.8-79.8,70.2-144,99.2-64.2-28.9-114-58.4-144-99.2-24.9-33.9-27.6-77.2-28.5-133-0.857-57.6-0.910-115 0-173z");
shieldPath.setAttribute("style", "stroke: white; stroke-width: 3;");

var fieldShape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
fieldShape.id = "fieldFill";
fieldShape.setAttribute("x", "0");
fieldShape.setAttribute("y", "0");
fieldShape.setAttribute("width", "450");
fieldShape.setAttribute("height", "450");

var fessShape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
fessShape.id = "fessFill";
fessShape.setAttribute("x", "0");
fessShape.setAttribute("y", "225");
fessShape.setAttribute("width", "450");
fessShape.setAttribute("height", "225");

var createSVG = function(name, fill, color, path) {
    var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svg.setAttribute("style", "height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;");

    var clipPath = document.createElement("clipPath");
    clipPath.id = name + "Clip";
    svg.appendChild(clipPath);

    clipPath.appendChild(fill);

    if(path) svg.appendChild(path);

    var use = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
    use.setAttribute("class", name);
    use.setAttribute("clip-path", "url('#" + clipPath.id + "')");
    use.setAttribute("href", "#fieldShield");
    use.setAttribute("fill", color);
    svg.appendChild(use);

    return svg;
}
```

Comment: You create the use element correctly with createElementNS but fail to create the clipPath element with that function, instead incorrectly creating it with createElement which does not work for SVG elements.

Comment: Ugh. I can't believe I missed that. Would you like to add that as an answer? It works with that change.

Comment: it's a typo really. I voted to close it.